# mostrar tablas dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysqli

en una base de datos llamada producciones tengo 5 tablas y quiero que se muestren el nombre de la tabla con sus respectivos campos y en cada campo su dato.
tengo el siguiente codigo PHP:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT table_name AS nombre
            FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'producciones' order by nombre asc"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql); 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$row['nombre'];
                $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql2);
                echo "<div class='col-md-6 border'>
                <h1>".$row['nombre']."</h1>";
                while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                    $sql3 = "select *  as dato from ".$row['nombre']."order by id desc limit 1";
                    $result3 = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql3);
                    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                        echo"<table class='table table-hover table-dark'>
                            <td class=border>".$roww['Field']."</td>
                            <td>".$row3['dato']."</td>
                        </table>
                        </div>";
                    };
                };
            }
            ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

el codigo asi como esta me tira error, pero si saco el tercer query y tercer while, hace lo que quiero (mostrar el nombre de la tabla con sus respectivos campos) que estaria haciendo mal que no me muestra los datos correspondientes? estoy empezando a creer que hice mal en crear tablas independientes por cada produccion

Comment: como que creaste tablas diferentes por cada produccion? explica eso, porque ese puede ser la raiz de no solamente este error, si no montones mas...

Comment: Donde trabajo hay 5 producciones de productos: pollo asado pechito Carré y osobuco y arme una tabla x cada corte. Una tabla para el pollo y así sucesivamente y no todas las tablas tienen la misma cantidad de campos

Comment: Son considerablemente distintos los campos de cada tabla? Porque sino me parece que lo más conveniente es tener una sola tabla con todos los productos y agregar un campo que determine el tipo de producto. Algo como `product_type_id`  y en otra tabla el listado de tipo de productos.

Comment: Bueno. No parece ser correcto, pero con tan poca informacion no puedo decirlo. tu modelo suena "raro", ya que si tuvieras 20 tipos de productos tendrias 20 tablas, y seguro no esta bien. Creo que esa es la raiz de tu problema. ahora, seguro se puede solucionar tu codigo.. pero no suena bien tu modelo

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar el mensaje de error que te da?

Comment: Estas son las tablas:
        carre
        id
inicial
costillita
carre_sin_hueso
ribs
solomillo
huesito
grasa
diferencia
fecha_produccion

pechito
id
inicial
pechito
matambrito
diferencia
fecha_produccion

osobuco
id
inicial
osobuco
hueso
diferencia
fecha_produccion

asado
id
inicial
asado_premium
asado_oferta
asado_super_oferta
falda_premium
entraña
vacio
matambre
grasa
diferencia
fecha_produccion

pollo
id
inicial
alitas
pata_muslo_tc
pechuga_tc
menudos
carcasa
grasa
diferencia
fecha_produccion

Comment: @OscarGarcia el error que me tira ese codigo es el siguiente:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd1/716/10694716/public_html/includes/tablas.php on line 16

Comment: La línea 16 imagino que es la de `while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))`, ¿verdad?

Comment: @OscarGarcia si, se refiere a ese while

Comment: @RicardoMartinLeguizamon, ¿Probaste la modificación que te propuse? Prueba la modificación en el SQL y, además, blinda el código como te indico para que encaso de que siga habiendo un error SQL te indique cuál es.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, no estoy en mi pc y no se xq no puedo abrir el hosting en este momento, en cuanto pueda lo hare y te aviso como me fue

Comment: Por cierto, una duda: ¿quieres mantener esta forma de crear la tabla o prefieres que te propongamos una más eficiente (sin usar `SHOW COLUMNS`)?

Comment: todo lo que mejore el rendimiento es bienvenidos, como estoy recien aprendiendo, leyendo fue la que encontre

Comment: @OscarGarcia como seria esa forma mas eficiente?

Comment: Paciencia, es fin de semana. Mañana te muestro cómo.

Comment: Hecho. He modificado mi respuesta para mejorar el código. Al final expongo un listado de mejoras realizadas al código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La siguiente línea contiene un error SQL:

```
$sql3 = "select *  as dato from ".$row['nombre']."order by id desc limit 1";
```

Estás concatenando inmediatamente después del nombre de la tabla el texto `order`, sin separación y, además, estás asignando el alias `dato` a todos los campos.

Debería ser:

```
$sql3 = "select * from ".$row['nombre']." order by id desc limit 1";
```

Para evitar futuros problemas deberías blindar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
$result3 = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql3);
if ($result3 === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($cxn)));
}
```

PD: Debes modificar tu código para soportar obtener un campo anidado:

```
<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row3[$roww['Field']]) . "</td>
```

De esta manera obtendrás el valor del campo enumerado y no un campo estático llamado `dato` que ya no existe (no se puede hacer un alias de `*` como te indiqué anteriormente).

---

Una versión mejor optimizada de tu código podría ser:

```
<?php
$baseDeDatos = 'producciones';
/* Obtenemos las tablas de la base de datos */
$sql = '
  SELECT
    TABLE_NAME nombre
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = ?
  ORDER BY nombre ASC
';
/* Preparamos a consulta, asignamos el valor y la ejecutamos */
$consulta = mysqli_prepare($cxn, $sql);
if ($consulta === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($cxn)));
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta, 's', $baseDeDatos);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta) === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_stmt_error($consulta)));
}
/* Obtenemos el resultado para trabajar con él como de costumbre */
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulta);
if ($result === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($cxn)));
}
/* Iteramos cada tabla */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<div class="col-md-6 border"><h1>', htmlspecialchars($row['nombre']),
    '</h1>';
  /* Aquí presupongo que tienes correctamente configurado
      el juego de caracteres en PHP */
  $sql2 = '
    SELECT *
    FROM `' . mb_ereg_replace('`', '``', $row['nombre']) . '`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 2
  ';
  /* Realizamos la consulta */
  $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql2);
  if ($result2 === false) {
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($cxn)));
  }
  /* Obtenemos el primer y único resultado (LIMIT 1).
      NOTA: Editado para mostrar 2 (LIMIT 2) */
  while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo '<table class="table table-hover table-dark">';
    /* Ahora iteramos por cada campo del resultado */
    foreach($roww as $campo => $valor) {
      /* Mostramos en una fila (<tr>) el nombre del campo y su valor */
      echo '<tr><td class=border>',
        htmlspecialchars($campo), '</td><td>',
        htmlspecialchars($valor), '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Modificaciones hechas:

- A cada consulta le sigue una comprobación del resultado para detectar errores.
- Todas las salidas de datos al navegador van correctamente escapadas con [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars).
- Hacemos uso de [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli_fetch_assoc) en vez de [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli_fetch_array) para obtener una matriz cuyos elementos son únicamente los nombres de los campos y no se agregan índices numéricos (también se podría haber usado el parámetro `MYSQLI_ASSOC`).
- En vez de obtener los nombres de los campos que podrían ser obtenidos en un orden diferente al obtenido en la consulta SQL, obtengo los nombres de los campos de los índices del resultado.
- Uso consultas preparadas para proporcionar el nombre de la tabla de manera segura.
- Aunque lo ideal sería enumerar las tablas o filtrar su nombre, trato de escapar las comillas invertidas (<kbd>`</kbd>) en los nombres de tablas obtenidos de la consulta SQL (se presuponen hasta cierto grado "seguros") con soporte multibyte (utf8).
- Corrijo la apertura y cierre de las etiquetas HTML para que se visualice el contenido adecuadamente y cada registro en su propia tabla.

Comment: funciono!!! gracias por tu ayuda y me pondre a estudiar mas que todavia me falta largo camino veo

Comment: ffaa, todo lo que me falta aprender muchas gracias